# Multiple if and elseif conditions PHP

Tags: php

If I have 3 If conditions (A, B and C), I want to declare all possibilities, i write it like this :

```
if (A && B && C) {
    do this;
} elseif (A && B) {
    do this;
} elseif (B && C) {
    do this;
}
```

Now what if I have instead of 3, 6 conditions ? should I right 36 if / elseif statements ? or there is a short / smart way to write it ?

Thanks !

Comment: if you have 6 conditions, then you should sit back and analyze the logic to see just how much is repetitive. e.g. if condition E has no effect on anything else, then don't do a bunch of `A&B&C&D& !E & F`-type stuff.

Comment: You can do nested IFs that might reduce some of the overhead. I agree with Marc, look at your logic and see if there might be a smarter way to go about it.

Comment: Take a look at `switch()`.

Comment: @Brian `switch` is just for testing one expression against many different values, it's not very good for combinations of conditions.

Comment: @Barmar it depends. If you use `switch (true)` you can do math conditionals or boolean comparisons. `case  ($t < "1000"):` or `case in_array($t, range(0,20)):`

Comment: @Brian Yeah, I know about that silly trick. It doesn't allow any better organization that `elseif`. IMHO, it should never be seen outside code golf.

Comment: True, but it can still be used regardless. If Ops vars are booleans the use of `case ($a && $b && $c);` would work. The issue OP has is one of logic/approach.

Comment: I think there is no short way to mix all those possibilities. Anyway, my code looks similar to this

If ((!empty($A) && (!empty($B)  && (!empty($B)  ... etc...